# Photoshop Photo filter math

Tags: math, photoshop

Photoshop has a nice feature called Photofilter (Adjustments > Photo Filter). I've tried to understand the math behind it but no luck. It's not a standard blending and not a multiplication. By applying specific filter to white image I've found that it has a non-linear behavior which is different for each channel. Any one has suggestions where to look for ideas about how to mimic color photo filters? Thanks

Comment: An example or two would've been nice, for those (like me) who do n ot have photoshop installed.

Comment: @AVB here are few examples: Multiply (opacity 100%) [link](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/5330/multiply100.jpg) Photo filter (density 100%) [link](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/165/photofilter100.jpg) Multiply (opacity 50%) [link](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/5672/multiply50.jpg) Photo filter (density 50%) [link](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/250/photofilter50.jpg). As one can see at 100% (opacity and density) results looks quite similar but once density of the photo filter decreases it start look rather different from simple multiply + opacity version

Comment: I am looking for this same thing... did you find a better answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few JavaScript libraries with filter effects:

- [loupe.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/loupe/)
- [Grayscaler](http://kaioa.com/node/104)
- [AlphaJPEG](http://blog.jackadam.net/2010/alpha-jpegs/)